# Combining entries, filtering of Python dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, list, dictionary

I have two large lists that are filled with dictionaries. I need to combine the entries if a value from dict2==dict1 and place the newly combined matches somewhere else. I'm having trouble explaining it.

List one contains:

```
{'keyword':value, 'keyword2':value2}
```

List two:

```
{'keyword2':value2, 'keyword3':value3}
```

I want a new list with dictionaries including keyword1, keyword2, and keyword3 if both lists share the same 'keyword2' value. What's the best way to do this? When I try, I only come up with tons of nested for loops. Thanks

Comment: I think you're using language incorrectly.  Something like `{'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2'}` is a "dictionary", not a list; an individual member like `'k1':'v1'` is an "element" or "mapping".  Pedantic maybe, but it makes you harder to understand.

Comment: What should happen if the lists have different values for the same key? Which one wins? Or should the entry be removed or an Exception be thrown?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about "conflicts", i.e. that the same key is mapped to different values in two dicts, you can use the `update` method of dicts:

```
>>> d1 = {'keyword': 1, 'keyword2': 2}
>>> d2 = {'keyword2': 2, 'keyword3': 3}
>>> d = {}
>>> d.update(d1)
>>> d
{'keyword2': 2, 'keyword': 1}
>>> d.update(d2)
>>> d
{'keyword3': 7, 'keyword2': 2, 'keyword': 1}
```

Assuming your dicts are stored in a large list named `dict_list`:

```
total = {}
for d in dict_list:
    total.update(d)
```

Comment: OP writes that only shared values should be in the new list, so he does care about conflicts - he just didn't state how the program should behave in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over one dictionary, comparing individual elements to the other dictionary.  Like this, where `dict1` and `dict2` are the originals, and `dict3` is the result:

```
dict3 = dict1
for k in dict2:
    if k in dict1:
        # The key is in both dictionaries; we've already added dict1's version
        if dict1[k] != dict2[k]:
            pass # The dictionaries have different values; handle this as you like
    else
        # The key is only in dict2; add it to dict3
        dict3[k] = dict2[k]
```

You weren't clear on what behavior you wanted if the two dictionaries have different values for some key; replace the "pass" with whatever you want to do.  (As written, it will keep the value from `dict1`.  If you don't want to include either value, replace the `pass` with `del dict3[k]`.)